# WebView stays empty on iPad but not iPhone on iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, webview

I have developed an app for the iPhone. Now I want to support the iPad as well, so I have checked the necessary checkboxes in Xcode ("Devices" - "Universal").

When I start my app in the simulator, the default ViewController is opened and a web page is loaded. The default view controller consists of a web view, that fills the entire screen. The page loads fine on every iPhone simulator, but the screen stays empty on every iPad simulator.

Because the pages are loaded on the iPhones, I don't think it is a constraint problem.

I have also unchecked the property "Application requires iPhone environment" in the info.plist file, but this doesn't change anything.

The web view is used to authenticate with a web site, so I can not check any other view controllers.

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

```
<key>UIMainStoryboardFile~ipad</key>
<string>Main_iPad</string>   // storyboard name
```

Add this two line in your project's plist. To open plist file search `.plist` file. Right Click on it. Select open As source code and past above code.

Comment: There already is an entry called "Main storyboard file base name" in the info.plist. I think I would need to add your lines, if the Storyboards were different, but I want to use the same storyboard for both iPhone and iPad. I've added the line, but it still stays white.

Comment: i think you need to add storyboard name for iPad also. Pls try it.

Comment: I have removed the line for the default storyboard and added the two entries (iPhone and iPad). I chose the same storyboard name, the iPhone works and the iPad still does not work.